# Clarifying an example on field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I understand the construction of $\frac{\mathbb{R[x]}}{\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle}$ as a quotient ring. Namely, the elements are of the form $ax + b +\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$. I can add and multiply elements. If the degree of the coset becomes greater than 1, I can divide by $x^2+1$ and absorb the quotient into the ideal.

When I read, I encounter the following concepts which confuse me.

1. I have read:
   $$ x^2 + 1 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle = 0 +\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle \\ \implies x^2 + 1 \mapsto 0 \\ \implies x^2 = -1 $$
   This was used to simplify a computation like:
   $$ (x + 3 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle)(2x + 5 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle) \\ = (2x^2 + 11x+15 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle) \\ = 11x+13 + \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$$
   That $x^2 + 1 \mapsto 0\implies x^2 = -1$ seems like a "physicsy" formal manipulation. I'm taking a map between coset labels on LHS and the RHS has turned that mapping into an equality over the field of reals. Can I just do that?
2. I have read in multiple places the following statement:

   > $\frac{\mathbb{R[x]}}{\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle}$is a field containing the zeros of $x^2+1$

Can someone help me unpack the foregoing statement?

Comment: You yourself provided the reasoning : " If the degree of the coset becomes greater than 1, I can divide by $x^2+1$ and absorb the quotient into the ideal.". $2x^2 + 11x+15$ when divided by $x^2+1$ leaves the remainder $11x+13$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, of course you can eliminate any $x^2+1$ from the representation of a coset. For example $2x^2+11x+15+\langle x^2+1\rangle=2\cdot(x^2+1)+11x+13+\langle x^2+1\rangle = 11x+13+\langle x^2+1\rangle$. It does not mean that $x^2=-1$ but it simply means that $x^2+\langle x^2+1\rangle = -1+\langle x^2+1\rangle$. Therefore you can safely put $-1$ anytime you see $x^2$ to get a representation of the given coset.

About your second question. It is true that $A=\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$ is a field containing the zeros of $x^2+1$. This is because $\overline{x}\in A$ and $-\overline{x}\in A$ are the roots of that polynomial.

Comment: 1. Okay I buy: $x^2 + <x^2 + 1> = -1 + <x^2+1>$. How do I see this? I started unpacking the LHS and got stuck: an element of $x^2 + <x^2 + 1>$ would look like $x^2 + \sum_i r_i (x^2+1)^i$, I should be able to manipulate this to get $-1 + \sum_i r_i (x^2+1)^i$, right? 2. Why should it follow that the roots of the polynomial are in $A$? I suspect this is elementary, but I'm still getting used to all these new def'ns.

Comment: 1. Definition of the coset structure is this : for an ideal $I$ we have $a+I=b+I$ iff $a-b\in I$. Note that $x^2-(-1)=x^2+1\in \langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: 2. Well, just insert $\overline{x}$ to the polynomial. What do we get? We get : $\overline{x}^2+1=\overline{x^2+1}=\overline{0}$ where the last equality follows by the fact that $x^2+1+\langle x^2+1\rangle=0+\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: ^should it read $b+I$?

Comment: Yeah, I edited.

Comment: Almost there: to verify -- $\bar{x}^2 + 1 = (x + <x^2+1>)^2 + 1 = x^2 + <x^2+1>+1 = x^2 + 1 + <x^2+1>$  -- can I just commute that 1 like that?

Comment: You are using $(a+I)+(b+I)=a+b+I$.

Comment: wait I'm still a little confused, can you show how that helps commute the 1 in my computation?

Comment: This is the correct computation : inserting $\overline{x}$ to the polynomial $x^2+1$ means that computing $\overline{x}^2+\overline{1}=(x+I)^2+(1+I)=(x^2+I)+(1+I)=x^2+1+I=0+I=\overline{0}$ (these are just the definitions of the multiplication and the addition in the quotient ring). Note that $1$ in the polynomial $x^2+1$ represents the unit element $1+I$ in the quotient ring.